# Html entity for true minus symbol

Tags: html

I'm a typophile adding mathematical equations to my pages.

I've found questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009545/what-is-the-proper-html-entity-for-the-x-in-a-dimension) that have explained to use `&times;` instead of 'x' for a true multiplication symbol. But I can't find any questions that indicate whether an html entity exists for a true minus symbol instead of using a hyphen, en-dash or em-dash?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_math.asp), the HTML entity is `&minus;`

Comment: A more informative answer than my own anyway. Cheers