# Displaying check mark and cross instead of boolean TRUE and False?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a Django/MySQl/bootsrap website where my view displays some boolean column values. Is there a way to display check mark and cross mark instead of showing TRUE or False? It can either be a .svg file or HTML code for check mark and cross. Any brilliant mind around has done the same?

### Here is my code:

```
<tr class="table_content">
    <td>{{ sku.sku }}</td>
    <td>{{ sku.gsa }}</td>
    <td>{{ sku.service_category }}</td>
    <td>{{ sku.product_category }}</td>
    <td>{{ sku.product_description }}</td>
    <td>{{ sku.unit }}</td>
    <td>${{ sku.msrp }}</td>
    <td>${{ sku.channel_price }}</td>
    <td>{{ sku.volume_pricing }}</td>
    <td>{{ sku.comments_sku_description }}</td>
    <td>{{ sku.new_sku }}</td>
    <td>{{ sku.price_requested }}</td>
    <td>{{ sku.to_be_retired }}</td>
</tr>
```

The last 3  return boolean values. I am trying to display either a .svg file of checkmark and cross or simply html code for checkmark  and cross.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the html you can use the **tick symbol** in this unicode format `&#10004;` result `✔`

And also you can use the **times symbol** in this html format `&times;` result `×`

---

Reference :

[Tick symbol in HTML/XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658044/tick-symbol-in-html-xhtml)

[What is the proper HTML entity for the "x" in a dimension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009545/what-is-the-proper-html-entity-for-the-x-in-a-dimension)

---

**EDIT**

**Option 1 - works but it is not suggested**

If `{{ variable }}` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`
you can check it with javascript

```
<td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if( "{{ variable }}" === "FALSE" ) {
            document.write("×");
        } else {
            document.write("✔");
        }
    </script>
</td>
```

The above option is NOT SUGGESTED. If you use it in a wrong way it will create problems and security holes (at least escape your strings).

**Option 2 - better in this case (suggested)**

In the Django template, check if true or false

```
<td>{% if variable == True %}&#10004;{% else %}&times;{% endif %}</td>
```

---

For more fancy icons check [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

---

**EDIT 2:**

For true/false variables also check [tuky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58379884/3709257), it is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the more concise `yesno` template filter (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno):

```html
<td>{{ variable|yesno:"✔,✘" }}</td>
```

It also supports an optional 3rd value that will be used, if `variable` is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if variable  %}
   <span class="fas fa-check-square"  style='font-size:24px;color:green'></span>
{% else %}
   <span  class="fas fa-window-close"  style='font-size:24px;color:red'></span>
{% endif %}
```